# Help prove the following set of functions vanish at infinity

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

A real valued function $f$ is said to vanish at infinity if the following holds : $$|f(x)|\rightarrow 0 \ \ when\ \ |x|\rightarrow \infty$$

Given the set $$C_{\infty}(X)=\{f\in C(X):\{x\in X : |f(x)|\ge {1\over n}\} \ is\  compact\ \forall n\in \mathbb N  \}$$ where $X$ is a *completely regular Hausdorff* topological space and $C(X)$ denotes the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R.$ It says that functions of this set vanish at infinity. But how?

Now , for any fixed $n\in \mathbb N$  $\{x\in X : |f(x)|\ge {1\over n}\} \ is\  compact$ say $K.$ Then, for $x\in X\backslash K,|f(x)|\lt {1\over n}$ . Thus when $n\rightarrow \infty,$ for some certain $K,x\in X\backslash K,|f(x)|\rightarrow 0.$ But I did not find $x\rightarrow \infty$  part here.

Please help me prove it. I know I am making some serious mistake here.

Comment: Help you prove what?  You haven't stated what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Um, you don't fix n. K= {x:|f(x)| >= 1/n} is compact for all n.  Thus closed and bounded.  As x-> infinity can x "remain" in a closed and bounded set?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this approach can help you:

Let's suppose that $f(x)$ doesn't vanish when $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, then:

$\exists \epsilon>0 \mbox{ and }\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, with $|x_n|\rightarrow\infty$ such that $|f(x_n)|>\epsilon,\; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

But taking $n$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n}<\epsilon$, we have that $\{x_n\}\subset K$, for some compact $K$. Now, as $K$ is compact in a Hausdorff space and all the elements of the succesion $\{x_n\}$ are in $K$, the limit of $|x_n|$ can't be $\infty$.

Then, we have: $\forall \epsilon>0$ and all succesions $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $|x_n|\rightarrow\infty$, $\exists$ a finite set $N_{\epsilon}\subset\mathbb{N}$ : $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\mbox{\\}N_\epsilon$, $|f(x_n)|<\epsilon$.

Hence, $f$ vanishes at infinity.